# find the difference and take the minimum then take the first node and create an edge

Tags: c++

need your help again because my problem can see the end , maybe even today.

Please give me a help .

`for (int Edges = 0; Edges < dimenstionOfEdges; Edges++){//this loop takes the first line`

```
    double Min = DBL_MAX;
    for (int newSt = 0; newSt < newStations; newSt++)//this loop goes over all stations
    {

        float firstsol = 0;//i check which stations are on the same line
        float secondsol = 0;//here is the same
        float thirdsol = 0;//here is the same
        firstsol = (busEdges[Edges].y2 - busEdges[Edges].y1) / (busEdges[Edges].x2 - busEdges[Edges].x1);
        secondsol = (apointCollection2[newSt].y - busEdges[Edges].y1) / (apointCollection2[newSt].x - busEdges[Edges].x1);
        thirdsol = (busEdges[Edges].y2 - apointCollection2[newSt].y) / (busEdges[Edges].x2 - apointCollection2[newSt].x);

        if (firstsol == secondsol || firstsol == thirdsol)//if they are equal means that some nodes are on the same line
        {

            file2 << newSt << " ";//it works because i have a list of all right nodes
            necessarycoor.x2 = apointCollection2[newSt].x;
            necessarycoor.y2 = apointCollection2[newSt].y;
            values.push_back(necessarycoor);//i add them into my vector
            //should i do it here ? The idea is that i need to take each coordinate of all nodes which are on the line and create a line. For example after first edge iteration , i have 3 nodes , now i need to check which two are closer to each other and take them and create a line then i go to another and etc. So for example i need to have the line(route) 0-145-12. It means i go from 0 to 145 and then from 145 to 12 , the order doesn't matter i can also go from 12 to 145 and from 145 to 0

        }


    }
    //or here? I can do it here and i have already done but the problem is that the id of each node should be the same. It means if i go from 0-145-12 , it should be 0-145-12 . If i put it here then i have 0-1-2. Just as i start loop and proceed. 

        file2 << endl;
        number.clear();
    }
```

Please read and give me a helpful advice. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `busEdges`? `apointCollection`? ` necessarycoor`?

Comment: busedges it is an iterator for each edge. My edge has x1 y1 x2 y2 . Apointcollection it is a vector that has all coordinates for each station(newStations). necessarycoor(i decided to add coordinates of stations which are on the same line) . I have already an edge but i need to rebuild it because i have more new stations